# Refrescar valor asignado a un select2

Tags: select2

Básicamente cuando selecciono un registro para verlo, ya tengo cargados los estados, pero al seleccionar un estado, carga municipios y luego colonias. Pero conforme voy seleccionando valor no alcanza a cargar/seleccionar el siguiente.
Estoy usando la librería select2

```
$("#estado").val(id_estado).trigger('change');
await cargaMunicipios();
$("#municipio").val(id_municipio).trigger('change');
await cargaColonias();
$("#colonia").val(id_colonia).trigger('change');
```

Ya utilicé los metodos async y await pero el problema está en que cuando uso .trigger('change'); desencadena una solicitud de cambio usando la función siguiente, llamando a la función 2 veces y le quita lo asíncrono.
Solo quiero que actualice el valor.
Ya usé .trigger('change.select2'); y sigue actuando de la misma manera.

Estaba usando la librería de selectpicker y daba bien, es solo que es muy lenta, select2 me permite cargar por medio de un json de golpe sin necesidad de recorrer el json. Recorrer el json en parte me hacía lenta la página

Comment: O no entiendes el funcionamiento de await ni de .trigger... o no tengo ni idea que es lo que pretendes hacer... en que parte de la página se ejecuta ese código que pones arriba? El cargaMunicipios debería ejecutarse una vez se seleccione un estado, pero segun lo que pones todo se ejecuta secuencial, no cuando el usuario seleccione algo

Comment: El registro ya está guardado, digamos:

Usuario | id_estado | id_municipio | id_colonia
Pipe      |       8       |         222      |    19862

Si yo quiero ver el registro, no tengo cargados todos los combo para seleccionar el valor, sino que cada uno carga una vez carga el primero.
Si no usara una librería normalmente funciona así.
`$("#estado").val(id_estado);
await cargaMunicipios();
$("#municipio").val(id_municipio);
await cargaColonias();
$("#colonia").val(id_colonia);`
Vuelvo a decir, solo quiero que actualice el valor sin desencadenar el trigger